# How to make an XNA game entirely transparent

Tags: c#, xna, transparency

http://www.grumpybread.com/download/gop-gop-goop-goop/

Trying to modify this persons code to have the keyboard transparent so you can see through it. If i make

```
spriteBatch.Draw(keyboardBaseIMG, keyboardPosition, Color.White);
```

into

```
spriteBatch.Draw(keyboardBaseIMG, keyboardPosition, Color.White * 0.5f);
```

all it does is make the letters less noticeable.

Comment: Do you mean transparent? Opaque means you can't see through it.

Comment: "keyboard opaque so you can see through it" - opaque is the opposite of transparent.

Comment: ok then i guess i do mean transparent. id like it so i can have the program as an overlay

Comment: Have you tried multiplying `Color.White` with 0?

Comment: @user1801067 If you make it 100% transparent, you won't be able to see it at all at which point it's pointless to draw it in the first place. What you probably want to do is edit the image and make everything except the key borders and symbols 100% transparent.

Comment: tried that, and it kept a black background but no buttons anymore.

Comment: @itsme86 i tried manually edditing the images to about alpha = 100, but it didnt change the program at all

Comment: @user1801067 100 alpha (depending on editor, really 255 alpha is max) means 100% opaque. You want to make the bits that you want to see through have 0 for alpha. Leave the bits that you want to see (key symbols, etc.) at 100 alpha.

Comment: @itsme86 in the code, they background image you see on the link i posted is one  png file, and when you press a button it displays another image over that one. im trying to make the general keyboard about 50% transparent so that its not just a big black box.

Comment: @user1801067 Also, be aware that XNA by default accepts Magenta (#FF00FF) as 100% transparent if you don't want to rely on the alpha channel.

Comment: i think my issue is im trying to edit it in the wrong place. No matter what i do to that line it only changes the color of the text when im not pressing anything. I tried magenta and it legit just made it magenta

Comment: So i completely removed the draw lines, and it still shows a back background for the program itself

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49438/discussion-between-user1801067-and-itsme86)

Comment: What is it you want to 'see through it'? If you want to see what's behind the window then you need to make the window itself transparent.

Comment: @microvirus ill try looking that up, but would you mind giving a small explanation?

Answer (score 0):

What I don't understand is why you simply don't:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(keyboardBaseIMG, keyboardPosition, Color.Transparent);
```

Isn't that kinda what you want?

I'm not going to question your reason for wanting to make it transparent (since you guys seem to have had enough fun in chat, but I didn't see anyone bring this up!)

Mona

Comment: its not the sprite i want to make transparent, its the game window itself